# The king wanted him killed VS The king wanted him to be killed

Tags: syntactic-analysis, participles, object-past-participle

Do the following sentences mean the same thing or are they different?

> - The king wanted him killed.
> - The king wanted him to be killed.

Please use examples to explain the differentiations.

Comment: Superficially they mean the same thing.  But the second form would be rare and generally followed by a "but ..." phrase explaining why this didn't happen.

Comment: @HotLicks: I can't see why preference should be any different with [wanted it to be over / wanted it over](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=wanted+it+to+be+over%2Cwanted+it+over&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwanted%20it%20to%20be%20over%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwanted%20it%20over%3B%2Cc0), and the evidence from that chart suggests the two forms are about equally common. More importantly, it seems the ***...to be...*** version is gaining ground, and may soon be *far* more common.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - When I Ngramed them the second was maybe a third as common as the first (and generally in a "but" context).

Comment: @HotLicks: I won't deny I did a bit of cherry-picking before using the specific example in my earlier link - the shorter version is still far more common with [wanted you here / wanted you to be here](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=want+you+here%2Cwant+you+to+be+here&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwant%20you%20here%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwant%20you%20to%20be%20here%3B%2Cc0), for example. But my gut feel is that *in general* the trend is for ***to be*** to be included more often these days.

Comment: Don't forget *“The king wanted to have him killed.”*

Comment: To some extent they are synonymous. But the first does carry a stronger suggestion that the king has the power to make it happen, or even that he has already given orders for it to be carried out.